# ISerializable - Serializing singletons

Tags: c#, serialization, iserializable

The ISerializable interface only provides a method to serialize the object. The deserialization
process is managed by a constructor.

The problem is, that constructor cannot return an instance, because the constructor CREATES a new instance.

In my implementation, there are several attributes corresponding to singletons instantiated and maintainded somewhere else.

I need the deserialization process to get that instance and assign to the attribute, instead of creating a new instance.

The constructor approach is not suitable for this.

In Java, you would call the ReadResolve() method, is there a C# equivalent?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: @user1275011 I see you haven't ever accepted an answer. In all of the questions you've posted, if someone posts something you believe to be correct, then mark it so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your classes which save a reference to the singleton implement IObjectReference.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx